# PDF file generation. Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, minio

I am forming a pdf file. When generating a file locally in Idea - pdf is generated correctly. And if you send this file to MiniO S3 - instead of Russian letters, the symbols '#' are generated

I myself tried to specify the encoding explicitly via metadata.setContentType ("application / pdf; charset = utf-8"); Does not help :-(

Now I'm more inclined to add fonts. Tell me how I can add this to the existing code.

Thank you in advance!

```
@SneakyThrows
    public byte[] createDocument(PaymentInstructionModel model) {
        WordprocessingMLPackage word = Docx4J.load(new ClassPathResource("template.docx").getInputStream());
        MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = word.getMainDocumentPart();
        Map<String, String> variables = objectMapper.convertValue(model, new TypeReference<>() {});
        mainDocumentPart.variableReplace(variables);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Docx4J.toPDF(word, os);
        return os.toByteArray();
    }
```

```
        byte[] document = documentService.createDocument(model);
        String key = String.format("%s/%d-%d-%d_Платёж_№%s.pdf",
                event.getPaymentNumber(),
                event.getPaymentDate().getYear(),
                event.getPaymentDate().getMonthValue(),
                event.getPaymentDate().getDayOfMonth(),
                event.getPaymentNumber());

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(document.length);

        amazonS3.putObject(S3Buckets.CLIENT_PAYMENT_PDF_BUCKET, key, new ByteArrayInputStream(document), metadata);
```

Comment: May be using the library IText?
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf

Comment: Your code does not appear to be using iText.

Comment: '''
byte[] docBytes = documentService.createDocument(model);
Document document = new Document();
BaseFont helvetica = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(helvetica, 12, Font.NORMAL);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
document.open();
document.add(new Chunk(Arrays.toString(docBytes), font)); // TODO
document.close();
'''

Answer (score 0):

try this method:

```
public String escapeHtml(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return value
                .replaceAll("\u001F", "")
                .replaceAll("&", "&amp;")
                .replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
                .replaceAll(">", "&gt;")
                .replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!
I rather need to add fonts when generating a PDF file